# boost::test, junit XML output

Tags: xml, boost, junit, report, boost-test

I select a framework for unit tests in C++
The best (for me) solution is boost::test, because it goes in boost :)

But there is 1 problem - the framework must be able to generate XML output in JUnit format, but by default boost::test can generate either human-readable or own XML formats

- (as I understand) I can write my own (custom) generator

So the question: does someone know the fastest way to make boost::test generate reports in JUnit format?

Comment: JUnit doesn't have an XML output. Ant does, hudson/jenkins do. Which XML format are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in unit test reports. Looks like I need an Ant one.  (http://junitpdfreport.sourceforge.net/managedcontent/PdfTranslation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost 1.62 provides built-in support for the JUnit format (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/log_formats/log_junit_format.html).

Comment: For those wondering how several loggers can be specified: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/logger.html

Comment: and this page says nothing about how to use it. As usual, boost documentation is the worst...

Comment: Agree with IceFire. Someone asked a very specific question. It is always the worse when someone just points you to horrible documentation. Sanket C answer works great and they don't have to dig through documentation to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Many a times the test could emit logs to stderr/stdout. If one needs only JUNIT format to log we can use the --logger option

```
./test --logger=JUNIT,all,reports.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom report formatter (implement interface results_reporter::format). Next you can create an instance of the formatter and register it inside your test module initialization function or global fixture.

Comment: No you don't. You can just do what Sanket C suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can generate results of boost tests in a JUnit format by setting `--log_format=JUNIT`.

If you want to run a binary named test:

```
./test --log_level=all --log_format=JUNIT > reports.xml
```

This will generate a reports.xml file in JUnit format. The `log_level=all` is for loading all details of the tests.